# changing css with jquery ui slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div that has a border of 10px. What I want to do is change the size of the border by moving the jQuery UI slider widget.

HTML

```
<h1>Choose Your Size!</h1>
<div id="map">
<div id="detail">
    <div id="slider"></div>
     <div class="dataPt"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/NWztP/1/

Answer (score 1):

Never used this before, just looked at http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            //console.log(ui.value);
            $('.dataPt').css({borderWidth: ui.value});
        }
    });
  });
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWztP/2/)

To maintain a circle

```
$('.dataPt').css({borderWidth: ui.value, borderRadius: ui.value * 2});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NWztP/3/